# Google maps has grey section

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am working on a web application using PHP Laravel framework, javascript and jQuery.

I am working on the integration with google maps API via Javascript but I have strange behavior as shown in the picture

[image]

I don't know why I have the grey section in this strange way

here is my js code

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('my_map'), {
 center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
 scrollwheel: false,
 zoom: 8
});
```

Any help will be appreciated , Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably a CSS issue. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: thanks for help, it was caching issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a caching problem, After I revert to the basic sample mentioned above I'd have to clear cache and it now working perfectly[image]

Answer (score 1):

**check on of the following solutions**:

- check the `position` of map container ;
- increase `z-index` of map container;
- try to clear browser cache press CTRl+Shift+Delete if you are using **Chrome**
- try it on another browser