# Google Maps: Horizontal Grey Lines across the Screen when Initialized

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I am trying to render an instance of google maps in my webapp using the Google Maps API.

When the map initializes, it renders with thick horizontal grey lines.

How can I get rid of these grey lines?

NB:

- The issue is not zoom-related.
- I have the same problem on all my Browsers, which are at the latest versions.
- none of the fixes in [Google maps has grey section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926029/google-maps-has-grey-section) have solved my problem.

Below is an image of what the current output.

[google map horizontal grey lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHU3G.png)

html.erb

```
<div id="map" class="map"</div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<%= Rails.application.secrets.google[:maps][:api_key] %>&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

js

```
function initMap() {
 new gravy.train.Map('map', {
  center: {lat: 51.21, lng: 0},
  zoom: 8
 });
}

gravy.train.Map = function(id, options) {
 this.container = document.getElementById(id);
 this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.container, options);
}
```

css

```
.map {
 height: 400px;
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a styling issue on your side. Can you see this behavior on sample page https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple?

Comment: It displays fine on the example in the link. No grey lines

Answer (score 1):

We had the same thing occur for our maps API. We found the problem to be 1 line of CSS in our global.css file. The setting was "max-height: 90%;" for "img" like this:

```
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 90%;
    }
```

Commented out the "max-height: 90%;" and no more horizontal grey bars on the maps!